# Loop instruction in assembly not working

Tags: loops, assembly, nasm

**Solution found**
I found the solution to my problem, I push ecx at the begin and at the end I pop ecx. It is working for me, I don't know if this is an acceptable solution.

---

The loop in this code isn't working. The loop never stops. I have tried multiple solutions, but non of them seem to work.
My compiler is `nasm` and I'm running `x86 linux ubuntu`
I hope you guys can help

```
section .data
newLineSymbol db 0x0a
str0 db 'test',0x0a
str0len equ $-str0
str1 db 'test test test',0x0a
str1len equ $-str1

section .bss

section .text
global main
main:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, str0
mov edx, str0len
int 80h

mov cx, 10
repLoopBody0:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, str1
mov edx, str1len
int 80h
loop repLoopBody0
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cx` is the low 16 bits of `ecx`. Also what's that random `int 80h` before `repLoopBody0` for? Its string address just got messed up. Then later, you `mov ecx, str1`, so now the loop counter is, well, not a loop counter really since you keep resetting it. Also just don't use `loop` if you can help it.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an error description. Tell us what you expect the program to do and what it does instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl the loop never stops

Comment: @DaanWitte What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: @DaanWitte And it's kinda clear that the loop never stops: You set `ecx` to a nonzero value in each iteration, so the loop never ends.

Comment: @FUZxxl but how would I then print something out on the screen?

Comment: @DaanWitte: Since you want to use `ecx` for something else inside the loop, don't use the `loop` instruction.  It's slow, so you shouldn't use it anyway.  Use a dec/jnz on a different register.  You could have easily debugged this yourself with gdb, watching the value of `ecx` change as you single-step through your loop.

Comment: @DaanWitte Perhaps you could use a different register to store your counter.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your help, I will implement this method instead.